# Can't add new node to linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to write a function that adds new node at the end of likded list and the program terminates for unknown reasons. I've added `"Works for now"` stamps to visualise what's going on.
it looks like the program terminates right before the `if (*first == NULL) {...}`

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    int ID;
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    struct student *next;
};

void insertattheend(struct student **first)
{
    struct student *new = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    struct student *last = *first;
    int Idtemp;
    char Nametemp[50], Surnametemp[50];
    printf("ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &Idtemp);
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%s", Nametemp);
    printf("Surname: ");
    scanf("%s", Surnametemp);
    new->ID = Idtemp;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        new->name[i] = Nametemp[i];
        new->surname[i] = Surnametemp[i];
    }
    printf("Works for now\n");
    new->next = NULL;
    printf("Works for now\n");
    if (*first == NULL)
    {
        printf("Works for now\n");
        *first = new;
        printf("Works for now\n");
        return;
    }

    while (last->next != NULL)
        last = last->next;

    last->next = new;
    return;
}

void printlist(struct student *oof)
{
    while (oof != NULL)
    {
        printf("ID: %d\nName: %s\nSurname: %s ", oof->ID, oof->name, oof->surname);
        oof = oof->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct student *head = NULL;
    head = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    char operation;
    // a - insert
    printf("Choose operation: ");
    scanf("%c", &operation);
    if (operation == 'a')
        insertattheend(&head); // add element

    printlist(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Choose operation: a
ID: 12
Name: John
Surname: Nhoj
Works for now
Works for now
```

I've tried everything i could've think of.
Does anybody know how to make this work? Thanks for help

Comment: Your understanding of linked lists is flawed. You don't add nodes at the end by iterating over all nodes. You add a node by inserting it at the head, so it's only one action instead of iterating over all nodes to find the tail.

Comment: `struct student *head=NULL; head=malloc();` Your insertion requires `head` to be `NULL` initially. But that code means that `head` is never `NULL` and you in fact have a head node with unintialised/garbage values in it.  Remove the `malloc` line.

Comment: The first node you add (`head`) did not get any properties. It is uninitialised. What do you expect when you print an uninitialised array of characters? But worse: what do you expect `next` to point to? It could point to anywhere and thus causes UB.

Comment: `new->name[i] = Nametemp[i];` You might think about `strcpy`

Comment: @Cheatah what's wrong with adding at the end? If you want to preserve the order in your list, adding at the head isn't what you want.

Comment: @Gerhardh I concur. Normally a list structure containing a head, tail, and an optional size, are used in such cases, as it affords fast inserts on both ends, but even a poor-mans single-pointer bare linked list is certainly sometimes akin to tail insertion, even if it isn't the most efficient thing (reality, it's the *least* efficient thing).

Comment: <O/T> consider adopting [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) or similar for variable and function names ... makes for much easier reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your head insertion is needlessly complex. You can significantly shorting it by reading into a temporary `student` rather than a raft of otherwise-unrelated buffers. A semi-complete example appears below:

```
void insertattheend(struct student **first)
{
    // this is where we'll read our data first
    struct student s = {0};

    // TODO: ALL of these need proper error checking to ensure
    //  they succeeded
    printf("ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &s.ID);
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%49s", s.name);
    printf("Surname: ");
    scanf("%49s", s.surname);

    // march 'first' down the pointer chain until it addresses 
    // the last pointer in the list (which wil be the 'head' 
    // pointer itself if the list is empty, or the 'next'
    // member of the last node if the list is not empty.
    while (*first)
        first = &(*first)->next;

    // allocate a new node
    *first = malloc(sizeof **first);
    if (*first == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate new list node");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // structure copy 's' into the location pointed to by
    //  the pointer pointed to by 'first'
    **first = s;

    // done
}
```

Second, your `main` is needlessly allocating space for a node pointed to by `head`, when in reality it should simply start as NULL and allow the insertion function to manage it from there. The semi-full program appears below. I suspect you'll encounter other problem, some of which I've subtly addressed here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    int ID;
    char name[50];
    char surname[50];
    struct student *next;
};

void insertattheend(struct student **first)
{
    // this is where we'll read our data first
    struct student s = {0};

    // TODO: ALL of these need proper error checking to ensure
    //  they succeeded
    printf("ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &s.ID);
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("%49s", s.name);
    printf("Surname: ");
    scanf("%49s", s.surname);

    // march 'first' down the pointer chain until it addresses 
    // the last pointer in the list (which wil be the 'head' 
    // pointer itself if the list is empty, or the 'next'
    // member of the last node if the list is not empty.
    while (*first)
        first = &(*first)->next;

    // allocate a new node
    *first = malloc(sizeof **first);
    if (*first == NULL)
    {
        perror("Failed to allocate new list node");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // structure copy 's' into the location pointed to by
    //  the pointer pointed to by 'first'
    **first = s;

    // done
}

void printlist(const struct student *oof)
{
    while (oof != NULL)
    {
        printf("ID: %d\nName: %s\nSurname: %s\n", oof->ID, oof->name, oof->surname);
        oof = oof->next;
    }
}

void deletelist(struct student *lst)
{
    while (lst)
    {
        struct student *tmp = lst;
        lst = lst->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct student *head = NULL;
    char operation;

    printf("Choose operation: ");
    scanf(" %c", &operation);
    if (operation == 'a')
        insertattheend(&head); // add element

    printlist(head);
    deletelist(head);
    return 0;
}
```